# Django annotation is giving two diffrent result in two cases

Tags: django, django-annotate

I have two cases:

Case 1:

```
qs = Stockdata.objects.annotate(sales_sum=Coalesce(Sum('salestock__quantity')))
qs2 = Stockdata.objects.annotate(purchase_sum=Coalesce(Sum('purchasestock__quantity_p')))
```

Case 2:

```
        qs = Stockdata.objects.annotate(
           sales_sum = Coalesce(Sum('salestock__quantity'),0),
           purchase_sum = Coalesce(Sum('purchasestock__quantity_p'),0))
```

The result which is coming in Case 1 is absolutely perfect but when I am trying Case 2 the result is coming multiplying the no of entries I made..

Can anyone tell me what is the reason for this and can give a perfect solution to rectify the errors because the 2nd Case is what I need to use in my project...

Thank you

**Edit**

I have tried this according to the response:

```
        qs = Stockdata.objects.annotate(
        sales_sum = Subquery(
            Stock_total_sales.objects.filter(
                sales = OuterRef('pk')
                ).values(
                    'sales'
                ).annotate(
                    the_sum = Sum('quantity')
                ).values('the_sum')
            ),
        purchase_sum = Coalesce(Sum('purchasestock__quantity_p'),0)
```

But having a bit problem of using "the_sum" in further subtraction of annotated values..

I had done this previously:

```
        qs1 = qs.annotate(
        difference = ExpressionWrapper(F('purchase_sum') - F('sales_sum'), output_field=DecimalField()),

    )
```

Anyone any suggestion what should I use instead of sales_sum.

Thank you

Comment: In the latter, you make two `JOIN`s, hence you will count the same `salestock__quantity` a number of times (the number of related `purchasestock`s). So the `JOIN` acts as a multiplier.

Comment: Thank you @WillemVanOnsem for the reason... So can you tell me the solution to break the JOIN in 2nd CASE because I need to do further subraction of annotated queryset, which I have done using 'ExpressionWrapper'..

Comment: you use a `Subquery` instead.

Comment: Hmmmm...Trying that...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [multiple annotate Sum terms yields inflated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12108710/multiple-annotate-sum-terms-yields-inflated-answer)

Comment: Did I have done anything wrong in my code..??