# How to fix multiple annotate Sum give wrong answer

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

i want to annotate observation_taken count and observation_given count in that group.

models : -

```
class Observation(TimeStampedEnumeratedUUIDModel):
rubric = models.ForeignKey('rubrics.Rubric', related_name='observations')
gro`enter code here`up = models.ForeignKey(
    'access.Group', related_name='group_observations')
observer = models.ForeignKey(
    'access.UserRoleAccount', related_name='user_observations_taken')
observee = models.ForeignKey(
    'access.UserRoleAccount', related_name='user_observations_given')
is_published = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class UserRoleAccount(TimeStampedUUIDModel):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="user_role_account")
role = models.ForeignKey(Role, related_name="user_role_account")
account = models.ForeignKey(Account, related_name="user_role_account")
```

[multiple annotate Sum terms yields inflated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12108710/multiple-annotate-sum-terms-yields-inflated-answer)

```
UserRoleAccount.objects.filter(pk='24f4a032-3f83-4123-8330fa60fcbb880c').annotate(count=Sum(Case(When(user_observations_taken__group=grp,then=1)),default=0,output_field=IntegerField(),distinct=True)).annotate(count1=Sum(Case(When(user_observations_given__group=grp,then=1)),default=0,output_field=IntegerField(),distinct=True))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution which works for me.

`ura = UserRoleAccount.objects.filter(pk='24f4a032-3f83-4123-8330-fa60fcbb880c').
annotate(taken_count=Count(Case(When(user_observations_given__group=grp,then='user_observations_given')),distinct=True)).
annotate(given_count=Count(Case(When(user_observations_taken__group=grp,then='user_observations_taken')),distinct=True))`