# I want add two annotation for two foreign keys using Django. How do I do this?

Tags: django, foreign-keys

```
# models.py
from django.db import models

class Elephant(models.Model):
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    families = models.ForeignKey(Families, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

```
def add_families_and_locations_counts(elephants):
    return elephants.annotate(
            families_number=Count('families'),
            location_number=Count('location')
    )
```

```
# Run
output = add_families_and_locations_counts(elephants)
```

In the above, the counts are incorrect. How do I get the correct counts?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [multiple annotate Sum terms yields inflated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12108710/multiple-annotate-sum-terms-yields-inflated-answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to count the **distinct** foreign key model instances.

Update your annotations function to the below:

```
def add_families_and_locations_counts(elephants):
    return elephants.annotate(
            families_number=Count('families', distinct=True),
            location_number=Count('location', distinct=True)
    )
```