# Timeout running SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, django, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to using the aggregation features of the django ORM to run a query on a MSSQL 2008R2 database, but I keep getting a timeout error.  The query (generated by django) which fails is below.  I've tried running it directs the SQL management studio and it works, but takes 3.5 min

It does look it's aggregating over a bunch of fields which it doesn't need to, but I wouldn't have though that should really cause it to take that long.  The database isn't that big either, `auth_user` has 9 records, `ticket_ticket` has 1210, and `ticket_watchers` has 1876.  Is there something I'm missing?

```
SELECT 
    [auth_user].[id], 
    [auth_user].[password], 
    [auth_user].[last_login], 
    [auth_user].[is_superuser], 
    [auth_user].[username], 
    [auth_user].[first_name], 
    [auth_user].[last_name], 
    [auth_user].[email], 
    [auth_user].[is_staff], 
    [auth_user].[is_active], 
    [auth_user].[date_joined], 
    COUNT([tickets_ticket].[id]) AS [tickets_captured__count], 
    COUNT(T3.[id]) AS [assigned_tickets__count], 
    COUNT([tickets_ticket_watchers].[ticket_id]) AS [tickets_watched__count] 
FROM 
    [auth_user] 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [tickets_ticket] ON ([auth_user].[id] = [tickets_ticket].[capturer_id]) 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [tickets_ticket] T3 ON ([auth_user].[id] = T3.[responsible_id]) 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [tickets_ticket_watchers] ON ([auth_user].[id] = [tickets_ticket_watchers].[user_id]) 
GROUP BY 
    [auth_user].[id], 
    [auth_user].[password], 
    [auth_user].[last_login], 
    [auth_user].[is_superuser], 
    [auth_user].[username], 
    [auth_user].[first_name], 
    [auth_user].[last_name], 
    [auth_user].[email], 
    [auth_user].[is_staff], 
    [auth_user].[is_active], 
    [auth_user].[date_joined] 
HAVING 
    (COUNT([tickets_ticket].[id]) > 0  OR COUNT(T3.[id]) > 0 )
```

**EDIT:**

Here are the relevant indexes (excluding those not used in the query):

```
auth_user.id                       (PK)
auth_user.username                 (Unique)
tickets_ticket.id                  (PK)
tickets_ticket.capturer_id
tickets_ticket.responsible_id
tickets_ticket_watchers.id         (PK)
tickets_ticket_watchers.user_id
tickets_ticket_watchers.ticket_id
```

**EDIT 2:**

After a bit of experimentation, I've found that the following query is the smallest that results in the slow execution:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT([tickets_ticket].[id]) AS [tickets_captured__count],
    COUNT(T3.[id]) AS [assigned_tickets__count],
    COUNT([tickets_ticket_watchers].[ticket_id]) AS [tickets_watched__count]
FROM 
    [auth_user] 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [tickets_ticket] ON ([auth_user].[id] = [tickets_ticket].[capturer_id]) 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [tickets_ticket] T3 ON ([auth_user].[id] = T3.[responsible_id]) 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [tickets_ticket_watchers] ON ([auth_user].[id] = [tickets_ticket_watchers].[user_id]) 
GROUP BY 
    [auth_user].[id]
```

The weird thing is that if I comment out any two lines in the above, it runs in less that 1s, but it doesn't seem to matter which lines I remove (although obviously I can't remove a join without also removing the relevant SELECT line).

**EDIT 3:**

The python code which generated this is:

```
User.objects.annotate(
    Count('tickets_captured'), 
    Count('assigned_tickets'), 
    Count('tickets_watched')
)
```

A look at the execution plan shows that SQL Server is first doing a cross-join on all the table, resulting in about 280 million rows, and 6Gb of data.  I assume that this is where the problem lies, but why is it happening?

Comment: What kind of indexes do you have on tables?

Comment: @NenadZivkovic Whatever django added - but good point, I'll check them.

Comment: You are right that it takes too long. I would get the execution plan to look at it and also set statistics on for io and time to see what's holding it up. Can you also post the code that resulted in this query? The query doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: @jtseng The execution plan shows that its getting stuck at the joins, but it seems to be cross-joining everything then evaluating the `ON` clauses as `WHERE` afterwards, resulting is several billion rows. I assume this is the problem? The python code is pretty much a direct translation of the SQL code.  I'm trying to produce a report showing the number of tickets in different groupings for each user.

Comment: Are you getting the right results? It looks like you would count some tickets multiple times. I would send out a query for each group.

Comment: @jtseng Ah, no, I'm not. I was so focused on the time that I didn't look at the results! I have actually re-implemented it as 3 separate queries now, which works much better.  I'm still not clear on why it doesn't work like this though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server is doing exactly what it was asked to do. Unfortunately, Django is not generating the right query for what you want. It looks like you need to count distinct, instead of just count: [Django annotate() multiple times causes wrong answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265190/django-annotate-multiple-times-causes-wrong-answers)

As for why the query works that way: The query says to join the four tables together. So say an author has 2 captured tickets, 3 assigned tickets, and 4 watched tickets, the join will return 2*3*4 tickets, one for each combination of tickets. The distinct part will remove all the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

what about this?

```
SELECT auth_user.*, 
   C1.tickets_captured__count
   C2.assigned_tickets__count
   C3.tickets_watched__count

FROM 
auth_user
LEFT JOIN
( SELECT  capturer_id, COUNT(*) AS tickets_captured__count 
  FROM tickets_ticket GROUP BY capturer_id ) AS C1 ON auth_user.id = C1.capturer_id
LEFT JOIN
( SELECT  responsible_id, COUNT(*) AS assigned_tickets__count 
  FROM tickets_ticket GROUP BY responsible_id ) AS C2 ON auth_user.id = C2.responsible_id
LEFT JOIN
( SELECT  user_id, COUNT(*) AS tickets_watched__count 
  FROM tickets_ticket_watchers GROUP BY user_id ) AS C3 ON auth_user.id = C3.user_id

WHERE C1.tickets_captured__count > 0 OR C2.assigned_tickets__count > 0
--WHERE C1.tickets_captured__count is not null OR C2.assigned_tickets__count is not null   -- also works (I think with beter performance)
```